# How to match regex in repetitive pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a text of this format :

```
a=b, // c=d  f=0x83 t= "some_string"
```

and would like to go over it using regex pattern so each time i take the left-operand and the right operand of the "="
i.e. i want to extract first "a" and "b" then "c" and "d" etc...

I tried this regex :

```
".+=.+"
```

But the right operand give the rest of the sentence instead of only "b".

Answer (score 0):

If your data does not contain the empty string values ​​and the characters from these - ",", " ", "/", then you can do this:

```
import re

s = 'a=b, // c=d  f=0x83 t= "some_string"'
ss = re.split(r'[= ,/]', s)
print(ss)
sss = [x for x in ss if x != '']
print(sss)
```

```
['a', 'b', '', '', '', '', 'c', 'd', '', 'f', '0x83', 't', '', '"some_string"']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', '0x83', 't', '"some_string"']
```